# How to convert sine to exponential form?

Tags: voltage, sinusoidal

In this question, he converted the sinusoidal voltage to exponential voltage.

what's the formula used here ? This is not the same one used in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4mHf-KhZu44)

[image]

Here is the formula derived in the video

[image]

Comment: Euler's relation.

Comment: It's not complete, the equation derived in the video linked is not the same

Comment: well you don't seriously expect me  to watch the video, do you?

Comment: J or more usually j is the electrical engineer's version of the mathemetician's i, the square root of -1.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is the most basic mathematical expression in harmonic analysis: Euler's relation. This is basic math, not EE.

Comment: *He converted the sinusoidal voltage to exponential voltage.* No, he expressed the signal in a **complex** form. Note the \$J\$ in front of \$J*150*e^{J * 500 *t}\$.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Sorry, I edited the question

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Alright, What's the formula used because mathematically, the two sides are not equal

Comment: They are equivalent.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Can you show me how they are equivalent. I really tried but I can't get to one from the other

Comment: I agree with @ahmedosama  , they are not mathematically equivalent. Mathematically, sin x = (e^jx - e^-jx)/2j. What is going on, is that electrical engineers tend to ignore the fact that one needs to add or subtract the complex conjugate to get a real value (or take the Re part).

Comment: I think they are phase shifting the Euler formula 90 degrees with the J at the front since the real part of Euler is given in terms of cosine  but your source function is given in sin. A sin is a 90 degree phase shifted cosine. More obvious if you change Euler to complex cartesian form and multiply by J. And they omitted taking the real part. It's sloppy.

Comment: By multiplying by J and not -J they also phase shifted it 90 degrees in the wrong direction to get the real parts strictly equal, but since it is the only source it doesn't matter since phases only have meaning relative to each other, so long as you shift all phases by the same amount. As written the real parts are actually negatives of each other and not even equal. Real sloppy. In light of all this sloppiness and omissions I vote to reopen.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know about the video, but the Euler's relation

\$e^{jx} = \cos(x) + j\sin(x)\$

where j = \$\sqrt{-1}\$, x = \$ \omega t\$

...means that the real portion Re(j\$e^{j\omega t}\$) = -\$\sin(\omega t) \$ or  Re(j\$e^{-j\omega t}\$) = \$\sin(\omega t) \$

So I think there are two things:

1. Take the real part
2. There is a missing minus sign in the book.

Comment: But they are not mathematically equal, right ?

Comment: No they are definitely not mathematically equal. Equivalent representations (modulo that minus sign).

Comment: I don't know, but he did this exact same thing in many examples in the book, so It's probably not a mistake, he meant to write it this way. I guess I will ask my professor for it.

Comment: Usually examples use cos() rather than sin().

Comment: @Spehro ... possibly because cos(x) = cos(-x) while sin(x) = -sin(-x)?

Comment: @BrianDrummond Using cos gets rid of the *j* multiplier and the minus sign, so it's simpler, I assume.